# Organizing Cases by Department

Tags: case

I'm sure our situation isn't unique but I'm trying to find a way to separate cases that are slated for 2 different departments.  It's throwing off our reports and I suggested to my admin to use a filter, but she states that it will take forever based on the amount of reports we'd have to change.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you were to build sharing rules around cases to limit access by department, which would then prevent a user from reporting the same, you're likely going to have to create some sort of filtering option and adjust reports.  How many reports are you talking about?  Adding filters isn't THAT time consuming.

Comment: That's pretty close to an answer @HomerJ.

Comment: @Homer thanks.  You are correct.  I was just trying to get a second opinion and that's what I figured was the answer.